# Issues with UUID field in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, uuid

I am using UUID field as primary key for my models , eveything is working fine when I am adding data to models from my views but when I tried to add one row from admin it gives me error of empty string I think .

```
DataError at /admin/appname/modelname/add/
invalid input syntax for uuid: ""
LINE 1: ...053380+00:00' WHERE "tablename"."field" = ''
```

My UUID field looks like

```
pk_field = UUIDField(auto=True, primary_key=True, serialize=True, hyphenate=True)
```

Any solution ??

Comment: Can you provide full sql log? Which Django version you're using? If it's pre-1.8, which uuid field implementation you're using? Are there any related models that refer to this field?

Answer (score 1):

You may use native **Django 1.8** [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField). In case you just want **always** to return non-hyphenated and serialized to string python object, you only have to subclass UUIDField and override [from_db_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value) like this:

```
class CustomUUIDField(models.UUIDField):

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
            return value.hex
        else:
            return value
```

Then use your CustomUUIDField instead native Django's UUIDField. Remember: this will ONLY work on Django 1.8, not prior versions (nor Django 1.7).